# Distrubute elements of the list between hosts in the group (ansible)

Tags: ansible

I've got a problem with my own laziness.

I have a list of the similar tasks to do. They differ only by name. Let say it is  a folder name.

```
---
- vars:
   folders:
    - folder1
    - folder2
    - etc
  hosts:
   - host1
   - host2
   - etc
```

And I want somehow distribute 'folders' between hosts. Round robin, for example.

I want to have something like this in role playbook:

```
- name: Create folder
  file: path={{item}} state=directory
  use_next_from: folders
```

How can I express 'use_next_from' for ansible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a bunch of folders on a bunch of hosts then you really only need to create a regular task and run it on all the hosts:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: create folder
      file: path={{ item }} state=directory
      with_items: folders
```

If you need to create a nested loop to do something more complex on each host then you can use the [with_nested](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops) construct:

```
vars:
    folders:
        - folder1
        - folder2
    files:
        - file1
        - file2

tasks:
    - name: create folder
      file: path={{ item }} state=directory
      with_items: folders

    - name: create files in each folder
      file: path={{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }} state=touch
      with_nested:
        - folders
        - files
```

If you want to do something "round robin" style then it's going to be much more difficult.  Ansible is designed to perform all tasks on all defined hosts.  You would probably need to do something fairly complex like this:

```
vars:
    folders:
        - folder1
        - folder2
    files:
        - file1
        - file2
tasks:
    - name: create folder
      file: path={{ item[0] }} state=directory
      when: ansible_inventory_hostname == item[1]
      with_nested:
        - folders
        - hosts
```

Comment: Well, I know about looping, but I want an automatic distribution. Assign one ore more 'folders' to the 'hosts'.

Answer (score 0):

You want loops. [RTM on loops](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html).

If Bruce's post doesn't answer your question then perhaps you want [Looping over Parallel Sets of Data](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html).

Comment: Em... It's not about looping, it about selecting one item from list for each next host in the group...

Answer (score 0):

Since Ansible 2.5, there is the [`index_var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) directive for `loop_control`. Then you can do this:

```yml
---
- vars:
   folders:
    - folder1
    - folder2
    - etc
  hosts:
   - host1
   - host2
   - etc

- tasks:
  - name: Create folder
    file:
      path: "{{item}}"
      state: directory
    loop: "{{folders}}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: index
    when: inventory_hostname == hosts[index % hosts|length]
```

When you want to target a host group from inventory for example you can replace `hosts` by `groups.example` in the `when` statement.